# How to put my page numbers on the right side of the header?

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

I'm writing a `\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12t]{report}` and I would like to get my page numbers on the top right side of my pages (after the table of content) with `fancyhdr`.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12t]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}


\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents %Table of contents
\pagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage %The first chapter should start on an odd page.

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

Could someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The first page of the table of contents and the first pages of each cjhapter will use page style plain. So we must redefine page style plain (using `\fancypagestyle`. The second and following pages of the table of content will use the normal page style that is current. So if we use `\pagestyle{fancy}` we must make that completely empty. And then when the normal text starts we fill in the header with the page number.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

\tableofcontents %Table of contents

\cleardoublepage %The first chapter should start on an odd page.

\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{We begin}

\section{Test} 

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example has a typo (should be `12pt`, not `12t`), is missing an `\end{document}`, and has no actual body that would show the page number placement on ordinary pages. Further, it's unclear whether you actually want any page number on the Table of Contents page and, if you do, where it should go.

Try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents %Table of contents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage %The first chapter should start on an odd page.

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{We begin}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

I included a `\chapter` command so as to show that the page number will, by default, still be in the footer, centered. You may or may not want to change that.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help, I didn't include everything because my document is very long. I don't want page numbering on my table of content. I tried your solution and am still getting my page numbers on the center bottom of the pages for the pages with a \part, a \chapter etc. Do you know how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This solution still gets page numbers on the table of contents when it is more than one page. See my solution.